# Install pygame with miniconda3 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, raspberry-pi4, miniconda

Probably the solution to my problem is easy, I just do not have enough knowledge to solve it.
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry OS (buster) on it . It comes with python 2.7 and 3.7 preinstalled and they contain pygame package too.

In the meantime I installed miniconda3 and upgraded it to python 3.6. Now I would like to use pygame through this python.

Unfortunately whatever I try I always get some error messages. Probably there is a way to link the pygame in the preinstalled python 3.7 to my miniconda python, but I do not know how to do that. Here is a list what did I try and what error did I get.

0. I installed the following packages (thinking they could help, but not really):

```
sudo apt install libsdl1.2-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential libfreeimage-dev libopenal-dev libpango1.0-dev libsndfile-dev libudev-dev libasound2-dev libjpeg9-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libwebp-dev automake
sudo apt install libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-dev libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-dev
```

1. Copied the pygame folder from the python3.7/dist-packages to miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame. When I import the error message is:

   ```
   File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
   from pygame.base import *
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'
   ```
2. `sudo apt install python3-pygame`: Message:
   `python3-pygame is already the newest version (1.9.4.post1+dfsg-3).`
3. `pip install pygame==1.9.4`: Error:

```
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 1.2.15
    FONT    : not found
    IMAGE   : not found
    MIXER   : not found
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : found
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    PORTTIME: not found
    FREETYPE: found 22.1.16
    Missing dependencies
```

I guess here I need to install some packages but I do not know how.

4. I tried from conda too:

```
conda config --add channels cogsci
conda install -c cogsci pygame
```

Error message:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pygame

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/cogsci/linux-armv7l
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/cogsci/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rpi/linux-armv7l
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rpi/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-armv7l
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-armv7l
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-armv7l
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-armv7l
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

I see that conda does not see the repository, but I thought I have just added it with the command above.

Could someone tell me, how could I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to find out a solution to this problem. Basically tried to solve the problem in point 3. above. I had a few packages missing for pygame. Here are the packages that if you install pygame will not complane:

```
sudo apt install libsdl1.2-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential libfreeimage-dev libopenal-dev libpango1.0-dev libsndfile-dev libudev-dev libasound2-dev libjpeg9-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libwebp-dev automake
sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev   libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev
pip install pygame==1.9.4
```